# python, regex: What RegEx do I need?

Tags: python, regex

I have a large file that I need to use search through using RE's

Here is a sample of the file:

```
76360247039795},{"number":522141635,"catalog"
```

I need to print out only the digit stream that appears after {"number":

This file is too large to post all of and there is about 200 times this string appears. Which is why I think I need to use RE's and from my research I think what I need to use is something called a "look around" not sure though.

I have been trying this for ages please help

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a JSON file? http://www.json.org/ If so, `import json; data = json.loads(open("file").read())`

Comment: you have a 9 digit number in your example...

Comment: How is the start and end of string/file, i.e. is it possible to `eval` it??

Comment: @ka thanks must have miscounted, changed the question so its correct.

Comment: @hughdbrown this file is a json but the string is in other files I need to search that aren't jsons

Comment: So is this question about the files you first described or these other non-JSON files? Definitely use JSON for JSON files; it will be far easier. If this is really about some other files, show what they look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

with open('myLargeFile.txt', 'r') as myFile:
    numbersList = re.findall('{"number":(\d{9})', myFile.read(), re.DOTALL)
print numbersList
```

This will create a list that only contains 9 digit numbers that appear after the string `{"number":`

If the numbers you are looking for might have more or less then 9 digits, use this reg ex instead:

```
numbersList = re.findall('{"number":(\d{x,y})', myFile.read(), re.DOTALL)
```

, and replace x and y to fit your needs. x stands for the lowest number of digits that the numbers are allowed to have, and y for the highest. 
For example, if you want to find all numbers that have in between 5 and 9 digits, the reg ex would become:

```
numbersList = re.findall('{"number":(\d{5,9})', myFile.read(), re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: thanks, works brilliantly. but it appears the length varies. how do I change your answer to show the matches of different sizes?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s = '76360247039795},{"number":522141635,"catalog"'
nl = re.findall('"number":(\d{9})', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using python `re` module, define a pattern and find your pattern in a string `s`.

```
>>> s='76360247039795},{"number":522141635,"catalog"'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('number":([0-9]+)', s) #this pattern 
['522141635']
>>> re.findall('number":([0-9]{9})', s) #or this pattern works.
['522141635']
```

> (...) Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses
>   and the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been
>   performed

Comment: consider putting `"number` before the `"`

Comment: that would work but im sure ":[some numbers] appears anywhere else in the file so it would pick up other digit streams

Answer (score 0):

For your JSON data, do this:

```
import json
with open("filename.json") as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
```

Now assuming your file is a list of dictionaries, like this:

```
[
    {"number": 522141635, "catalog": "..."},
    ....
    {"number": 999999999, "catalog": "..."}
]
```

print out your numbers as:

```
for dictionary in data:
    print dictionary["number"]
```